# sort by field which is stored as string but sort as integer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made an error and generated  my Item model with string field instead of integer.
Here is my migration

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url

      t.text :photo

      t.string :price


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But right now I want to sort my items by price field and rails sorts it bad way because it is stored as string.
For example it thinks that price 9 is bigger than 1111111111.
Right now I order them like this:

```
@items=Item.where(:category_id => @active_category_id).order(:price)
```

What do I do?

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66468714/7425631) to do that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the column type. You can do it with the following migration:

```
class ChangePriceTypeInItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :items, :price, :integer
  end
end
```

The data in `price` column will be preserved if the string contained represents an integer value.

[image]

> By the way, I think a `price` needs to be a `decimal` not an `integer`. But, you choose.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@items = Item.where(category_id: @active_category_id).sort { |a, b| b.price.to_i <=> a.price.to_i }
```

this gets all with your category id and then compares the prices as integers instead of strings. It should give you the order you're looking for.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.