# Ordering by String that starts with Number - ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, natural-sort

I'm building Rails app and trying to order records in database by string column that starts with number.
How can I order by the number at first?
I'd rather ordering as SQL order than sorting by ruby method. Is there any way?

```
expected order
1.record1
2.record2
10.record10
```

```
present order
1.record1
10.record10
2.record2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `order by` `field + 0` to change the data type of `field` to a number implicitly:

```rb
Model.order("field + 0 ASC")

# similar `string`.to_i in Ruby
# `1.record1`   => 1
# `10.record10` => 10
```

Comment: How can I use this with default_scope?
I tried default_scope { order("apartment + 0 ASC") }

Comment: @CleberReizen
 `default_scope { order("apartment + 0 ASC") }` should be ok, it didn't work?